# what is the (extra) padding/margin of the first element after placing multiple number of elements next to each other using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The first element appears to have extra spacing on its right which I cant figure out where it is coming from. Can someone help me?

Here is the code I used:
http://jsfiddle.net/srabeat/tenx4y1c/1/

```js
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    $(".box").append('<div class="x"></div>');
}
```

```css
.box {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.x {
    color: #444;
    margin: 10px;
    height:10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #444;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <div class="x"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by white space and how do you think I can remove it?

Comment: Sorry, removed comment since I added an answer. It's the physical `white space` in your mark up (in this case, a line break) - If you use a developer tool like Chrome, and remove the line break (select "Edit as HTML"), you'll see the "space" clear up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your fiddle and removed the space and new line before the container closing tag. Because you are setting `display: inline-block`, it will be treated as text and spaces behind the tags will be rendered as well.

You can use `display: block; float: left; instead.`

http://jsfiddle.net/1ancpbfm/1/

Comment: WARNING: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2004/07/17/floats-dont-suck-if-you-use-them-right/

Answer (score 1):

Update your **.x** class CSS by adding `float: left;` to it.

Here is your updated **[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/tenx4y1c/3/)**

Comment: WARNING: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2004/07/17/floats-dont-suck-if-you-use-them-right/ One of the most costly parts of a project that I was working on was making alterations to a layout that made extensive use of float. Unless you really understand what you're doing, they can be a real PITA later.

Comment: @spender Good article.